# JPA proper way to get DTO from database

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have database schema like this:

[image]

Now I want to write JPQL query or maybe use some other technology to get items from database with their types and info if item is borrowed right now and by who (just one borrower column instead of whole borrows list). I could use just normal query to get items with their types with EAGER loading and it could work but the problem is with borrows. How to get information about borrowing without taking whole list of borrows from database (or if I really have to do it how to designate borrower in a proper way)?

Item is borrowed if it has borrow with borrow_date NOT NULL and return_date NULL. My Item class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Item extends BaseEntity {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private Integer pageNumber;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate releaseDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "items_types", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<Type> types;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private List<Borrow> borrows;
```

I tried use JPQL with constructor using new POJO object like ItemDto, it lets me get current borrower but this time problem is with types, constructor can't take list of Type object. This is my query

```
select new com.test.library.dto.ItemDto(i.id, i.isbn,i.title, i.pageNumber, i.releaseDate, 
a.firstName, bb.lastName, i.types) from Item i LEFT JOIN i.borrows b ON (b.returnDate 
IS NULL) LEFT JOIN i.author a LEFT JOIN b.borrower bb
```

`i.types` doesn't work, when I remove it, this constructor works fine, but I need item types to display it on my view, so what is the proper way to achieve this?  I use spring-data-jpa + JPA 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

JPA defines the constructor expression as follow :

```
constructor_expression ::=
         NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
constructor_item ::=
         single_valued_path_expression |
         scalar_expression |
         aggregate_expression |
         identification_variable
```

It does not allow collection-value expression (i.e `i.types` in your case ) in the constructor expression.

So , I think there are no standard JPA way to construct a DTO directly through query if your DTO contains a collection and you have to do this part of conversion manually.

Comment: By saying manually u mean make for loop and for every BookDTO query for types to database? Or you have some better idea?

Comment: @jgr . For manually,  I mean I would use fetch join to select the item fetch with its author and borrow. Then I will convert item to DTO by getting the property from item and the set the related DTO 's properties. It is an easy task but  you may think it is tedious. If yes,  you can resort to some DTO mapper library eg many of [choice] (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/java-object-to-object-mapper.html) for you to do this conversion for you

Comment: But if book was for example 1000 times borrowed, this query will take those 1000 objects related to book even though i just need one or zero, thats why i dont want take whole list of Borrow objects..I know i can handle it in Java 8 in easy way, but imo it should be handled while querying database.

Comment: @jgr . If you use eclipselink , you can apply a where condition for the fetch join , then it return the book with its borrows, but only the filtered borrows . Not sure if hibernate also have such behaviour.